# msi installer create folder using orca

Tags: windows-installer, orca

I am using orca to edit the msi installer file created in visual studio 8. I want to create a directory path (CONTENT_DIR) which is accepted from the user. That directory can be any where, not necessarily in the TARGETDIR.
How do i populate the directory and component table.
Example:
TARGETDIR can be: C:\programfiles\soft\sof1\
CONTENT_DIR can be: F:\final\content\

Now how should create the CONTENT_DIR folder. Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

It's possible but it's going to be more work then I'm willing to write up.  I'll give a couple tips on how I usually do it.

1) I would create the COTENT_DIR directory row as a child of TARGETDIR. When the user picks the value it will be 'delinked' from TARGETDIR and go where you want it to go.

2) I'd do all the ORCA work as a transform.  Then I'd write a script to apply the transform to the newly built MSI so that you don't have to keep redoing all the edits after each build.

Then again I'd really do all this in WiX in the first place... VDPROJ is limited in what it can do and I rarely use it.

Comment: Thanks christopher, can u suggest some links where i can find more info on this. Or just tell me how to delink the from TARGETDIR.

Comment: I am creating the mst file and using msitran tool to apply it.

Comment: Delinking simply means that when you do a type 51, type 35 or directory browse at runtime and assign a new value to the entry that it's parent is really no longer TARGETDIR.

Comment: Okie, thanks your comments really helped, its done. :) The approach told by you is correct so +1, but did not mark the answer correct because, no explanation is present for the solution.

Comment: What exactly were you looking for?  A complete solution showing table screenshots from ORCA for an MSI I don't have?

Comment: at least the tables that needed to be edited, in order to achieve this. So that if someone in future reads this question, he gets a clear picture.

Comment: You didn't provide any code samples so it's not possible to show any modifications.   It would be pointless to attempt to show MSI table modifications because the modifications would depend greatly on what your tables start off looking as.   I gave you a design and it solved your problem so I really don't understand your complaint.

Comment: FWIW,  this type of MSI hacking is good foundational knowledge but it's not a real practical way of authoring MSIs.  It's like using .Net to build a DLL and then hacking the IL meta data in the assembly to do something that language couldn't describe.  Use a better tool such as WiX, InstallAware or InstallShield to avoid the problem in the first place.

Comment: Sorry I meant Advanced Installer not InstallAware.